# How do you emulate a Bluetooth keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, emulation

Well I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on a Samsung R410 (newer version!) and I have many bluetooth enabled devices with horrible virtual keyboards, and I would like to connect them to bluetooth keyboards, but I don't have any so can't I use the keyboard on my laptop to control these devices? By the way my computer's bluetooth dongle is capable of such a thing. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The bluetooth keyboard emulation is handled by the client (your phone), not the server (Ubuntu). You need to find a bluetooth keyboard app designed to be compatible with Linux on your smartphone for a proper bluetooth keyboard experience.